# Backup and Restore privilege

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I have a windows server 2008 r2 and I want to give the built in Administrator acount backup and restore previllige

how can i do this?

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

The built in local administrator already has the required rights to back up and restore on the local computer so you don't have to do anything.